# How to normalize data with instrumentation ceiling?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation, generalized-additive-model

**Problem**: I'm looking to analyze a data set of airport visibility (1960-2015) in a generalized additive model (GAM), but the data set is not normally distributed.

- Prior to 1996, visibility was measured at all distances.
- Post-1996, new automated measurements have a ceiling of 16 km. Any visibility above 16 km is just recorded as 16 km.

Can I use the distribution of visibility 16 km or greater from pre-1996 and apply this to the 16 km data post-1996?

**More background**: Visibility is increasing due to a decrease in fog occurrence. The GAM model will provide insight into the relative importance of various meteorological factors on visibility (with the purpose of understanding its impact on low visibility events specifically). We cannot use methods such as Tobit Regression to treat 16 km as a ceiling and determine the distribution based on predictor variables because this would bias our GAM model.

Another thing to consider is that we know visibility has *increased* from pre-1996 to post-1996. Thus, the distribution of high 16+ visibility events may look different over time. However, values above 16 km are not critical to our research question, as this is already very, very clear visibility. My goal is just to make the data normal to enter into the GAM model in a way that's justifiable. We tried a number of methods to tranform the data (informed by this article https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/tips-recognizing-and-transforming-non-normal-data/) to no avail.

**Current Data Histograms**: Excuse the differences in bin sizes (graphs were not made at same time). Should hopefully give a sense of what the distributions look like. Chose windows of Pre-1993 and Post-1998 to make sure I captured the instrumentation transition. Pre-1993, when log transformed, looks normalized, but post-1998 data clearly shows the instrumentation ceiling.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! This issue has driven me crazy. I'm still learning a lot about statistics and have definitely hit a wall.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, by normalize, I meant to transform the data to a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a right censored distribution and mark the values at 16km in the recent data only as being right censored; you know the true visibility for these observations is >= 16km but not the actual value.

You don't need to make data normal (Gaussian) to estimate a GAM; if you want to fit a Gaussian GAM then you want the *conditional* distribution of the response to be normal. The conditional distribution is the distribution of the response conditional upon (i.e. after taking account of) the values of the covariates in the model.

One way to fit the censored response in a GAM is via the *brms* package, which estimates models using STAN. The *gamlss*, *bamlss*, and (IIRC) the *VGAM* packages can fit these models also.